# I have to show/hide a message in a div below checkbox (in each record/row) when either one of the checkbox(pair) is checked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jsp, checkbox

I have a table with 4 column and n rows. Based on records i get from back end, the no. of rows increases. In each row, last column has two checkbox with different ids. On page load these check boxes may or may not be checked from backend. I have to show/hide a message in a div below checkbox when either one of the checkbox is checked. So it has two parts.
1. This message will be shown for already checked checkbox on  page load as the check box may be already checked 
2. This message will be shown for newly checked checkbox on click.

I tried using document.getelementbyID in $(document).ready(function(){}); but i get a list of row where each row has pair of checkbox in last column.

I tried to make changes in onClick event but the javascript called on click is on different jsp. Also, each checkbox hits its onclick event where i am not able to check whether the second checkbox is checked or not.

Comment: Provide your html and js code here

Comment: html code<div id="first">
<input type="checkbox" onclick="displayMsg(this,'first');" />
</div>
<div id="first">
<input type="checkbox" onclick="displayMsg(this,'second');"/>
</div>


<div id="msg" class="msg">
Div to display
</div>

Comment: function displayMsg(check,var){
if(this.checked){
$(".msg").show();
} else {
  if(var1=="first"){}
    
    if(var1=="second" ){
     if($(checkbox).closest("div").find('input[type="checkbox"]').is(':checked'));{
     $(".msg").show();
    }
   
}

Answer (score 0):

To solve this issue I've created a function that first clears out any text in the .msg div so that it's refreshed each time the function is run. Then each checked input has a function run on it that grabs it's labels text content, which identifies the individual checkbox name, and append that text to the .msg div. I run this function on page load and each time a checkbox is checked. You could probably optimize this function a bit but this gets the point across.

I've modified your markup and written new jQuery to handle this issue - https://jsfiddle.net/Shuaso/xebjc8gb/1/

HTML:

```
<div class="checkbox-container">
  <div id="one">
    <input type="checkbox" id="chk1" />
    <label for="chk1">Checkbox 1</label>
  </div>
  <div id="two">
    <input type="checkbox" id="chk2" checked />
    <label for="chk2">Checkbox 2</label>
  </div>
  <div class="msg "></div>
</div>

<div class="checkbox-container">
  <div id="three">
    <input type="checkbox" id="chk3" checked />
    <label for="chk3">Checkbox 3</label>
  </div>
  <div id="four">
    <input type="checkbox" id="chk4">
    <label for="chk4">Checkbox 4</label>
  </div>
  <div class="msg"></div>
</div>

<div class="checkbox-container">
  <div id="five">
    <input type="checkbox" id="chk5" />
    <label for="chk5">Checkbox 5</label>
  </div>
  <div id="six">
    <input type="checkbox" id="chk6" />
    <label for="chk6">Checkbox 6</label>
  </div>
  <div class="msg"></div>
</div>
```

jQuery:

```
function chk() {
  $(".msg").empty();
  $("input:checked").each(function() {
    var isChecked = $(this).siblings("label").text();
    $(this).parents(".checkbox-container").find(".msg").append(isChecked);
  });
};

//run the chk function on page load
$(function() {
    chk();
 });

// run the chk function on click of any checkbox
$("input").on("click", function() {
    chk();
});
```